# What does it mean to have a long breath? (metaphorically)

Tags: meaning

Here is a sentence:

> ". . . For Friml. Romberg. Victor Herbert. Maybe a little Mozart, too, where you **have to have the long breath**, but not the heavy stuff. The truth is, I did what I could with what I had. Not what I wanted, maybe, but what I could. I didn't have a penny when I landed here, after I ran away from Warsaw. I only knew that I had to change Czaferski to Safer. And a lucky thing, too, for all of us that I knew to do that. I thought I was a goner when I came to America."

Here is the link:
https://www.nytimes.com/1992/04/08/books/books-of-the-times-revolt-in-the-synagogue-unrest-in-the-choir.html

Comment: I've rolled back the edit.  By completely changing the quote you have made any existing answers useless.  You should edit to improve your question, but not to change it completely.

Answer (score 1):

It is a continuation of the previous paragraph, and it is possible that the automatic transcription may have introduced some errors.

The Character speaking says that he doesn't have a good enough voice for opera, but perhaps for operetta. He then gives examples of composers of Operetta (Friml, Romberg etc.) I wonder if those full-stops are actually commas in the original. He thinks he could also do some Mozart Operas (these tend to be lighter and shorter than later operas by Wagner, for example)

But for the Mozart you have to have a long breath (ie be able to sing a long passage on one lungfull of air). This is not an idiomatic expression. It seems to be an author trying to express broken English of a non-native speaker, (perhaps a person who speaks Yiddish natively).

The speaker then goes on to talk about his immigration to the USA, to explain why finiancal security is so important to him

Comment: "Mozart Operas (these tend to be **lighter and shorter** than later operas by Wagner, for example)" - and **better**.

Comment: I think I gave a bad example. Here is my original excerpt:In their approach to the antinomy of bM in state socialism the roads taken by Wolf BIERMANN and his teacher HEISE differed. Neither of them shrank back from necessary criticism of the GDR’s leadership. But while BIERMANN did this “aggressively and sought conflict”, what was important for HEISE, as also for Helmut SEIDEL and Lothar KÜHNE was “to have the long breath for changes in the country and the party and to be effective in bringing these about (through their thinking, writings, and above all teaching)” (TREBESS 2014).

Comment: bM: being a Marxist

Comment: That's probably a metaphor, but the English is incorrect. It is perhaps a literal translation of a German idiom.

Comment: James K. Could you possibly give an alternative?